# How to differentiate the docker image and the Dockerfile it is generate from?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to rebuild a docker image if the dockerfile source has been changed.

I was looking for storing the hash of the docker file in the Docker image but I wanted to know if there is a dedicated way to do this.

Comment: Do you mean automatically rebuild (where ever used) if the source has changed? or rebuild only if there is a change while using docker build?

Comment: I mean rebuilding the docker image if there is a change in its Dockerfile.

Comment: I'd just unconditionally re-run `docker build`.  Because of Docker's layer caching, this will be quite fast if neither the Dockerfile nor the underlying application source has changed.

Comment: Actully this stage is a little part from a bigger bash script, I just found a solution. I reply myself

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to use Docker LABEL in order to add custom metadatas to Docker object
https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/

Comment: Please [add context to your link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, and then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.